# React-router child-route navigation not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to follow the react-router tutorial [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/12-navigating) trying to navigate using a child route and it doesn't work.

For example given this route definition:

```
export default <Route path="wifi" component={ Wifi }>
    <IndexRoute component={WifiView}/>
    <Route path="list" component= {WifiListView}/>
    <Route path="connect" component={WifiConnectView}/>
</Route>;
```

If we are on `"/"` and navigate to `"/wifi"` we are good. The `WifiView` is presented however if if from `"/wifi"` we call `hasHistory.push('list')` it doesn't find the route. I would assume that the route is relative to its current location since I'm not using the `"/"` but that isn't being respected.

Also the document said:

> You can also use the router that Router provides on "context". First,
>   you ask for context in the component, and then you can use it...

But I don't see anything that mentions how to do that in TypeScript so I'm using the static `hashHistory`.

It looks like novice questions but I had nowhere to ask since the suggested Discord channels are all dead... Can anyone help with those?

Thanks! Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally found the replies to my questions...

1. As for today, react-router don't support relative navigation which means, it hast to navigate to the whole chain of routes and that is why `hasHistory.push('list')` doesn't work.
2. In order to get the `context.router` we need to use `withRouter` high order component but that isn't exposed on the TypeScript definition files they provide.

Comment: Wow, any source for 1.? I think this is my issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095663/router-push-changes-url-but-is-caught-in-404-refresh-same-url-works)