# Router.push() changes url but is caught in 404. Refresh same url works

Tags: react-router

I have a router something like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="items">
    <IndexRoute component={Items} />
    <Route path=":id" component={ItemDetail} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Router>
```

My `Items` component lists a bunch of items, each with a unique id.

The `ItemDetail` component... lets say just displays the `props.params.id` on screen.

When I click on an item, I call `router.push('items/'+id)` with the item's id.

The URL is updated correctly (e.g. `*/items/1234`), **yet it displays the `NotFound` component**.

If I then press F5 (i.e. reload the same URL), it **correctly displays the `ItemDetail` component**.

Any idea why this is the case? The URL is the same for both.

(Note: If I change `path=':id'` to `path='*'` it goes to the correct page on `router.push()`, but I lose access to `props.params.id`, of course.)

(Note: If I change all the paths to use a `/` at the start, the navigation is very broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `router.push()` uses an **absolute** path (with a leading `/`) only.

Using the relative path as above caused the URL to update, but the router did not update so the page was not displayed. Pressing F5 caused the full route to be loaded, and therefore displayed the page.

Therefore I needed:
`router.push('/items/'+id)`